# Problems using grunt-preprocess

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to use grunt-preprocess module but having difficulty getting ifdefs to work.

Here is my gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
// Configuratuion goes here

grunt.initConfig({

  preprocess : {

    options: {
      context : {
        DEBUG: false
      }
    },

    html : {
      src : 'dev/index.html',
      dest : 'dev/index.processed.html'
    }

  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-preprocess');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['preprocess']);
}
```

and this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">

<!-- @ifdef DEBUG -->
  <h1>Test Page</h1>
<!-- @endif -->

<!-- @exclude -->
<header>You're on dev!</header>
<!-- @endexclude -->

<p>Test Pragraph</p>

<div id="output"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I run grunt the code between the DEBUG ifdef is not removed (although the ifdef comments themselves are removed)

I have a feeling that I am missing some critical step that is not mentioned in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the documentation:

`@ifdef VAR / @endif` This will include the enclosed block **if VAR is defined** (typeof !== 'undefined')

your `DEBUG`-Var is defined (its value is a boolean), so your block will be included. remove it completly, and it should work:

```
options: {
  context : {}
}
```